# Why there seem to be no strict rules related to non-profit organization "overhead" in the US?

Tags: united-states, law, taxes

According to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/08/nonprofit-tax.asp), an organization can benefit from the non-profit tax status if it satisfies several conditions:

- have a purpose within a designated list
- an annual exemption form must be filed yearly (with some exceptions)
- files various other forms

However, I do not see some clear or strict rules related to the organizational "overhead". For example, [Cancer Fund of America](https://www.charitywatch.org/charities/cancer-fund-of-america-dissolved) (now dissolved) submitted some financial data that indicate a high overhead / low efficiency in spending the donations:

- only 13% of total expenses were spent on its programs
- the cost to raise 100$ was 80$
- the President/CEO had a compensation of $248,000

I wonder why non-profit status is allowed for some entities that spend most of the money outside of the programs themselves.

Comment: I don't know how strict the rules are but it's likely there are more than just those given by instestopedia.  I wondered by your example was dissolved so I searched for "cancer fund of america" and "scandal" and found a few articles indicating the person behind it was charged with fraud.  Here's one example https://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/20/business/4-cancer-charities-accused-in-ftc-fraud-case.html

Comment: "Why are there not rules for X?" has the generic answer: "No-one can agree what rules for X should be made"